# Why doesn't Gmail let me modify :from field Rails action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, gmail, actionmailer

I have a simple booking request form. When the user submits and a request gets created, an email with the request's data will be sent to one of the stakeholders (let's call her the admin). I'm using a free gmail account to send email with action mailer. The problem is the admin wants to reply directly to a customer when she clicks on "Reply" button in gmail, not reply to the sender. I tried editing the :from field like this but It didn't work. What are the options do I have to make this possible?

```
def sample_email(sender_email, user_name, booking_id)
    @booking = Booking.find(booking_id)
    mail(to: user_email, subject: "C2Sky booking request##{booking_id} from #{user_name}", from: @booking.email)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `mail` call pass in `reply_to: emailaddressforreply@whatever.com`

When anyone clicks reply now it will be set to `emailaddressforreply@whatever.com`